# Read webp images in java

Tags: java, image

Is there any simple way to read Image with ".webp" extenstion to BufferedImage object?
I need to crop image and ImageIo does not provide support for this extension

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/qwong/j-webp

Comment: Here is an example which loads a webp image into a BufferedImage: https://github.com/qwong/j-webp/blob/master/src/main/java/example/DecodeTest.java

Comment: @kol Strange that the project claims to be “100% Java” even though it’s just a wrapper for a native library, which doesn’t even appear to be the official libwebp.

Comment: A simple web search reveals there are at least four ImageIO providers for the WebP format.

Comment: If you need a 100% Java solution, I am working on one. It's not done, it's read-only and currently supports only VP8 (no lossless or alpha yet). But if you feel adventurous, you can have a look: [TwelveMonkeys WebP plugin](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/tree/webp).

Comment: @VGR Funny enough a simple web search had this question up as the top recommendation